# How to Write a Swift Function That Contains 2 Closures

Tags: swift, swiftlint

I'm relatively new to Swift and am receiving a `Multiple Closures with Trailing Closure Violation:...` warning from SwiftLint. My code that causes this looks like:

```
self.start(loggedIn: { _, error in
    //...
// below line causes warning
}) { [weak self] (someInfo: SomeInfo?, error: ErrorType) in
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This comment](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1801#issuecomment-383563362) details how one would go about this with an example:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
}, completion: { _ in
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

So in this case it would be:

```
self.start(loggedIn: { _, error in
    //...
}, started: { [weak self] (_: SomeInfo?, error: ErrorType) in
    //...
})
```

Comment: Yeah but they’re wrong. What you had to start with is just fine.

Comment: Yeah but unfortunately it's not up to me what rules and standards are enforced through *SwiftLint* in the CI system. :/